# Is the Global Request variable in Python/Django available?

Tags: python, django

I have written a plugin that sends a signal to activate my code. However, it doesn't send the user-request object to my code. I am looking for a way to retrieve the current request without modifying the main application. I cannot find any documentation related to global request (like `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in PHP).

I would like to know if there are any variable to do like that in Python/Django.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I know it, you define your Django view using a number of methods like:

```
def detail(request, some_param):
  # [...]
```

The parameter `request` contains information about the HTTP request. `request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` for example, returns the client's IP address.

If your plugin has something to do with requests, its classes and function probably will be instantiated/called from your view. This means you need to pass it the current `request` object, as it makes no sense to have a *global* request object around. 
In PHP, this is possible, as every request causes the whole code to be executed from scratch, but in Django requests are dispatched by a server and passed around in the framework using `HttpRequest` objects. Also refer to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/) part of the Django documentation for more information.

Comment: There are already exists views, and what I have to do is Plug-in which activate by that views, but that views haven't send the request object to my function. I also cannot alter  behavior of the code (views) of main application. So, I have to look for another solution.

Comment: This is hardly possible, see my updated post. Django can handle multiple requests at once, so there cannot exist some global but request-specific state. Maybe we can figure out a solution if you provide more information on what your plugin does, how it is structured, or even post some code.

Answer (score 23):

Django doesn't provide a global request object (it would actually be a thread local, not a global).  But there are a few techniques you can use to get the same effect yourself: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201008/global_django_requests.html

Comment: This is actually the most precise answer. How to get to the request outside a view. The solution is a bit hackish (installing middleware catching the request object for every thread in a dictionary), and this all encourages to pass the request down instead of globally retrieving it. Looks like a lot of `ModelAdmin.save_model(...)` overrides ahead (and worse still `ModelAdmin.save_related(...)`.

Comment: For django 2.0, [django-middleware-global-request](https://github.com/appstore-zencore/django-middleware-global-request) works

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK it is not available, except you make it available.

You can copy+paste the snippets provided in the other answers, or you can use this library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-crequest

> Middleware to make current request always available.

Answer (score 1):

you can attach it to current request via middleware and retrieve it back
https://github.com/jedie/django-tools/blob/master/django_tools/middlewares/ThreadLocal.py

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ned Batchelder's reply I've compiled a solution. Although I wouldn't recommend it for anything but debugging/troubleshooting. There's a better solution on the linked page.

Put module `m1` at a project root:

```
import inspect
def get_request():
    for f in inspect.stack():
        f_code = inspect.getmembers(f.frame, inspect.iscode)[0][1]
        f_locals = [v for (n, v) in inspect.getmembers(f.frame) if n == 'f_locals'][0]
        co_varnames = [v for (n, v) in inspect.getmembers(f_code) if n == 'co_varnames'][0]
        if 'request' in co_varnames:
            return f_locals['request']
```

Then in any other file:

```
import m1
print(m1.get_response().path)
```

You might want to make sure you don't introduce [reference cycles](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack). I haven't understood under which particular conditions I must do what exactly. Not that it matters in my case. But your mileage might vary.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is [`django-middleware-global-request`](https://pypi.org/project/django-middleware-global-request/).

It provides a way to get the request from anywhere once the request has been constructed by Django in the first place. It returns `None` if no request object is available, for example when running in a `manage.py shell`.

Comment: As an opinionated sidenote, I just can't fathom why Django doesn't provide this functionality out of the box. Seems like some kind of religious application of object-oriented progamming patterns. Of course the request object should be globally available in a web framework (okay, "threadally" available, whatever). It's a web framework. It's for web development, We're talking about the request object in a web framework.